# Removing list values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I am doing a beginner project on my own by making a blackjack game. It is going well and I can even choice 1 or 11 for Ace values. My problem is that I am trying to remove the cards from the deck for myself and also when I add a Dealer.

I thought I could do the .remove() function to remove it but that doesnt seem to work after running through the program with http://www.pythontutor.com/

Here is the deck code I am using

```
from random import randint
def CardDeck():
    #sets the card types and values
    CardValue = ['Ace','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K']
    CardType = ['Hearts','Spades','Clubs','Diamonds']
    Deck = []
    Card = randint(0,(len(CardValue )*len(CardType)))
    #This iterates all 52 cards into a deck
    for i in CardType:
        for j in CardValue:
            Deck.append(j + ' of ' + i)
    temp = Deck[Card]
    Deck.remove(Deck[Card]) #this should remove the card from the deck
    return temp
```

Comment: It looks like the card gets successfully removed from `Deck`, but then you exit out of the function one line later and `Deck` ceases to exist entirely. If you call the function again, a brand new `Deck` will be created, with absolutely no connection to the object that once had that name. If you want `Deck` to maintain its state over multiple function calls, you can't create it anew inside the function every time.

Comment: How would you suggest I do this? Just have everything outside of a function I suppose then?

Comment: BTW: in python the convention is to name functions and variables with snake_case and starting with small letter. Use CamelCase for class names.

Comment: Have one function to define a deck, which returns the deck, then a separate function to remove the card which accepts the deck as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you  for your insight.

Answer (score 2):

If looks like you are trying to get an item from a list and remove it from the list. There is the `.pop()` method for this case:

```
card = Deck.pop()
```

This will get the last item in the list, assign it to `card` and remove it from the list.

```
card = Deck.pop(1)
```

This will get the 2nd (index `1`) item from the list, assign it to `card` and remove it from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the insight I have figured out how I think I can accomplish this now and I am better for it! (also fixed my convention)

```
from random import randint
def card_deck():
    #sets the card types and values
    card_value = ['Ace','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K']
    card_type = ['Hearts','Spades','Clubs','Diamonds']
    deck = []
    #This iterates all 52 cards into a deck
    for i in card_type:
        for j in card_value:
            deck.append(j + ' of ' + i)
    return deck
```

Now I can break this out into card and remove_card functions, everything is clicking!

```
def new_card(deck):
    return deck[randint(0,len(deck)-1)]

def remove_card(deck,card):
    return deck.remove(card)


new_deck = card_deck()
card1 = new_card(new_deck)
remove_card(new_deck,card1)
card2 = new_card(new_deck)
remove_card(new_deck,card2)
```